# Create a custom transformer that removes outliers in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, outliers

I have a large dataset with about 300,000 rows and 35 columns. I'm trying to remove outliers using a custom transformer and later on use it with a Pipeline. Here's the test df:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':[100, 200, 250, 140, 800],'b':[0, 0, 1, 2, 1],'c':[-20, 0, 1, 2, 18]})

    a    b   c
0   100 0   -20
1   200 0   0
2   250 1   1
3   140 2   2
4   800 1   18
```

Here's my custom transformer:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class OutlierRemover(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, factor=1.5):
        self.factor = factor
        
    def outliers_iqr(self, X, y=None):
        X = pd.Series(X).copy()
        q1 = X.quantile(0.25)
        q3 = X.quantile(0.75)
        iqr = q3 - q1
        lower_bound = q1 - (iqr * self.factor)
        upper_bound = q3 + (iqr * self.factor)
        # filter only those rows that are greater than lower_bound and less than upper_bound, 
        #i.e. drop values outside the given interval
        X.loc[((X >= lower_bound) | (X <= upper_bound))] 
        
        return pd.Series(X)
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        return X.apply(self.outliers_iqr)


remover = OutlierRemover()
remover.fit(test)
remover.fit_transform(test)
```

When I apply the function to the df, it does nothing and returns the same data. My desired output would be a df without 0th and 4th rows as they contain outliers.

```
    a   b   c
1   200 0   0
2   250 1   1
3   140 2   2
```

Could someone point out my mistake and suggest a proper way?

Comment: You wrote *greater than lower_bound **and** less than upper_bound*; but used `|` i.e., **or**! Try replacing it with `&`. Also, need to assign back the result of `X.loc[...` to `X`, i.e., `X = X.loc[(X >= lower_bound) & (X <= upper_bound)]`.

Comment: with these, a dataframe where outliers marked as `NaN` could be returned; so you can also add `return X.apply(self.outliers_iqr).dropna()` to  `transform`.

Comment: Thanks, @MustafaAydın for your comment! Everything worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in the code:

1. The logic to keep the non outlier rows is incorrect. You should be using the '&' and not the '|' operator
2. You have not assigned the updated value of X after removal of outlier

Try modifying the second last line of the outliers_iqr() function to:

```
X = X.loc[((X >= lower_bound) & (X <= upper_bound))]
```